# How can i set li tag with extra characters?

Tags: html, css

I have a design style you can see in: http://jsfiddle.net/mohammad6006/Q6g3n/

in result you see test 2 that is in line 2

my div width is 220px and I don't want to display more characters on the other line

OR

when li text characters is more than 220px create new line but next li display in other line

for more describe:

```
<li>
    <a title="" href="">test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a title="" href="">test 3</a>
</li>
```

test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2 test2  characters is more than one line so extra characters display in new line and test 3 li display in other line too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `min-height`, so it uses your 28px height as base and the rest can expand it self.

You need to set your `#body-right ul li {}`
 **from** 
`#body-right ul li {height:28px;}` 

**to** 
`#body-right ul li {min-height:28px;}`

Updated [**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6g3n/2/)

Answer (score 0):

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6g3n/1/)

```
/css: min-height ist the solution
```

also i remove your background-image and replaced it with (cause there is no reason to use and image)

```
/css: border-bottom:1px solid red;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS :

Remove the style " height:28px" from #body-right ul li 
i.e

```
    #body-right ul li {
      background: url("../images/blog-body-right-line.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
      direction: rtl;
      line-height: 28px;
      list-style: none outside none;
      text-align: right;
      word-wrap:break-word;  

}
```